# How to find the longest chord perpendicular to the maximum chord through a polygon

Tags: r, geometry

I have irregular polygons defined by a set of points. I can find the the maximum chord location and length, but I'm not quite sure how to analyze the points to find the longest chord location and length that is perpendicular to the maximum chord.

Here's what I've got so far, some example data of points to define a polygon:

```
points_ex <- structure(list(V1 = c(68L, 67L, 66L, 66L, 65L, 65L, 64L, 63L, 
                                   62L, 61L, 61L, 60L, 59L, 58L, 57L, 56L, 56L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 
                                   54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 
                                   51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 
                                   45L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 42L, 
                                   42L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 
                                   38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 37L, 37L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
                                   35L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
                                   32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
                                   32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 
                                   33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
                                   33L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
                                   31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
                                   30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
                                   30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
                                   31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
                                   31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 
                                   34L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 
                                   44L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
                                   51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 
                                   54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 
                                   51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 
                                   53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
                                   63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
                                   76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 
                                   86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 
                                   92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 
                                   104L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
                                   112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
                                   122L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 
                                   127L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 129L, 
                                   129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 131L, 131L, 
                                   131L, 131L, 131L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 
                                   133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 131L, 131L, 130L, 130L, 
                                   129L, 129L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 
                                   129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 128L, 
                                   127L, 126L, 125L, 125L, 124L, 123L, 123L, 122L, 121L, 120L, 120L, 
                                   119L, 119L, 118L, 117L, 117L, 116L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 114L, 114L, 
                                   113L, 113L, 112L, 111L, 111L, 110L, 110L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
                                   108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
                                   106L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 103L, 103L, 
                                   103L, 103L, 103L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
                                   102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
                                   100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
                                   99L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 97L, 97L, 
                                   97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 
                                   96L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
                                   94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 93L, 93L, 92L, 92L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 89L, 
                                   89L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 85L, 
                                   84L, 83L, 82L, 81L, 80L, 79L, 78L, 77L, 76L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 72L, 
                                   71L, 70L, 69L), V2 = c(20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
                                                          28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
                                                          41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
                                                          54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
                                                          67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
                                                          80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
                                                          93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
                                                          105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 
                                                          116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
                                                          127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 
                                                          138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 
                                                          149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 
                                                          160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 
                                                          171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 
                                                          182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 
                                                          193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 
                                                          204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 
                                                          215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 
                                                          226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 
                                                          237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 
                                                          248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 
                                                          259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 
                                                          270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 
                                                          281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 
                                                          292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 
                                                          303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 308L, 308L, 309L, 309L, 309L, 
                                                          310L, 310L, 310L, 311L, 311L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 
                                                          312L, 311L, 311L, 310L, 310L, 310L, 310L, 309L, 308L, 307L, 306L, 
                                                          305L, 304L, 303L, 302L, 301L, 300L, 299L, 298L, 297L, 296L, 295L, 
                                                          294L, 293L, 292L, 291L, 290L, 289L, 288L, 287L, 286L, 285L, 284L, 
                                                          283L, 282L, 281L, 280L, 279L, 279L, 278L, 277L, 276L, 275L, 274L, 
                                                          273L, 272L, 271L, 270L, 269L, 268L, 267L, 266L, 265L, 264L, 263L, 
                                                          262L, 261L, 260L, 259L, 258L, 257L, 256L, 255L, 254L, 253L, 252L, 
                                                          252L, 251L, 250L, 249L, 248L, 247L, 246L, 245L, 244L, 243L, 242L, 
                                                          241L, 240L, 239L, 238L, 237L, 236L, 235L, 234L, 233L, 232L, 231L, 
                                                          230L, 229L, 228L, 227L, 226L, 225L, 224L, 223L, 222L, 221L, 220L, 
                                                          219L, 218L, 217L, 216L, 215L, 214L, 213L, 212L, 211L, 210L, 209L, 
                                                          208L, 207L, 206L, 205L, 204L, 203L, 202L, 201L, 200L, 199L, 198L, 
                                                          197L, 196L, 195L, 194L, 193L, 192L, 191L, 190L, 189L, 188L, 187L, 
                                                          186L, 185L, 184L, 183L, 182L, 181L, 180L, 179L, 178L, 177L, 176L, 
                                                          175L, 174L, 173L, 172L, 171L, 170L, 169L, 168L, 167L, 166L, 165L, 
                                                          164L, 163L, 162L, 161L, 160L, 159L, 158L, 157L, 156L, 155L, 154L, 
                                                          153L, 152L, 151L, 150L, 149L, 148L, 147L, 146L, 145L, 144L, 143L, 
                                                          142L, 141L, 140L, 139L, 138L, 137L, 136L, 135L, 134L, 133L, 132L, 
                                                          131L, 130L, 129L, 128L, 127L, 126L, 125L, 124L, 123L, 122L, 121L, 
                                                          120L, 119L, 118L, 117L, 116L, 115L, 114L, 113L, 112L, 111L, 110L, 
                                                          109L, 108L, 107L, 106L, 105L, 104L, 103L, 102L, 101L, 100L, 99L, 
                                                          98L, 97L, 96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 91L, 90L, 89L, 88L, 87L, 86L, 
                                                          85L, 84L, 83L, 82L, 81L, 80L, 79L, 78L, 77L, 76L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 
                                                          72L, 71L, 70L, 69L, 68L, 67L, 66L, 65L, 64L, 63L, 62L, 61L, 60L, 
                                                          59L, 58L, 57L, 56L, 55L, 54L, 53L, 52L, 51L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 
                                                          46L, 45L, 44L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 
                                                          33L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 
                                                          24L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                  -613L))
```

Looks like this:

[image]

I can find the maximum chord and draw that:

```
# draw max dimension points and line
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
df_dist = data.frame(as.matrix(dist(cbind(points_ex$V1,points_ex$V2))))
df_dist_x = df_dist %>% 
  mutate(row.1 = 1:nrow(df_dist)) %>% 
  mutate(Y = paste0("Y", row_number())) %>%
  gather(X,  distance, X1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  select(X, Y, distance) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(X, Y), parse_number)

df_dist_x_max <- 
  df_dist_x %>% 
  dplyr::filter(distance == max(distance)) 

points(points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[1],], col = "red", cex = 2)
points(points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[2],], col = "red", cex = 2.5)

segments(points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[1], 'V1'], 
         points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[1], 'V2'],
         points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[2], 'V1'], 
         points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[2], 'V2'],
         col = "green")
```

[image: Imgur]

And this is what I've been trying to get the longest chord perpendicular to the maximum length chord:

```
# transform the points and lines into spatial objects
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

points_sf <- st_as_sf(points_ex, coords = c("V1", "V2"))

newline = matrix(c(points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[1], 'V1'], 
                   points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[1], 'V2'],
                   points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[2], 'V1'], 
                   points_ex[df_dist_x_max$X[2], 'V2']), byrow = T, nrow = 2)

spline <- as(st_as_sfc(st_as_text(st_linestring(newline))), "Spatial") # there is probably a more straighforward solution...
position <- gProject(spline, as(points_sf, "Spatial"))
position <-  coordinates(gInterpolate(spline, position))
colnames(position) <- c("X2", "Y2")

segments <- 
  data.frame(st_coordinates(points_sf), position)  

segments$dist <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(segments)){
  segments$dist[i] <- 
    proxy::dist(data.frame(segments$X[i], segments$Y[i]),  
                data.frame(segments$X2[i], segments$Y2[i]))
}

# max width perpendicular to length axis
max_segment <- segments[which.max(segments$dist), ]
max_segment <- segments[segments$Y == max_segment$Y, ]

segments(max_segment$X[1], max_segment$Y[1],
         max_segment$X2[1], max_segment$Y2[1],
         col = "purple")

segments(max_segment$X[2], max_segment$Y[2],
         max_segment$X2[2], max_segment$Y2[2],
         col = "purple")
```

[image: Imgur]

Looks roughly ok, but my problem is that this method for finding the longest chord perpendicular to maximum chord only looks at one side of the maximum chord for the longest distance to the edge of the polygon.

I don't know how to measure every distance from edge to edge of the polygon that is perpendicular to the maximum chord.

This means my method doesn't generalise well at all, here it is applied to another polygon (data here: https://pastebin.com/XpiB6UnX because the `dput` output made this post too long)

[image: Imgur]

Obviously this is bad because the two purple segments should not be on the same side of the green segment, and it doesn't look like the right location at all for the longest chord perpendicular to the maximum chord.

How can I robustly find the longest chord that is perpendicular to the maximum chord?

Comment: Trying to digest this. Is this correct: the longest chord must be between two polygon vertices. The longest line perpendicular to the longest chord must start at a polygon vertex but might end between vertices. I'd use vector arithmetic to create a long line at right angles to the longest chord going through each of the vertices in turn, then st_intersection and save the longest. What if the polygon is concave and any of these lines are more than one segment?

Comment: Here's a two-liner that finds the i,j of the max of a matrix to replace all those incomprehensible pipes: `findmax <- function(m){
    v = which.max(m) - 1;
    c(v %% nrow(m)+1, v %/% nrow(m)+1)
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a full solution. First some functions:

```
## this returns the i,j of the largest elements in matrix `m`
findmax <- function(m){
    v = which.max(m) - 1
    c(v %% nrow(m)+1, v %/% nrow(m)+1)
}

## Return an sf line through a point at an angle of a given length
pline <- function(pt, angle, length){
    st_linestring(
        cbind(
            pt[1] + c(length,-length) * sin(angle),
            pt[2] + c(length,-length) * cos(angle)
        )
    )
}

## return the line that is the chord at angle perp.angle of length through any of the polygon vertices
max_perp_chord <- function(polygon, perp.angle, length){
    ## get polygon vertices
    pts = st_coordinates(polygon)[,c(1,2)]
    ## return the perpendicular lines
    perplines = lapply(1:nrow(pts), function(i){
        ## through the i-th vertex
        xy = pts[i,,drop=FALSE]
        perpline = pline(xy, perp.angle, length)
        ## intersect it with the polygon
        inters = st_intersection(polygon, perpline)
        inters
    }
    )

    ## get the vector of intersection lengths, find the largest
    perplengths = unlist(lapply(perplines, st_length))
    longest = which.max(perplengths)
    ## return the longest line
    perplines[[longest]]

}

### find the max length chord across all pairs of vertex points
max_chord <- function(polygon){
    ## get polygon coordinates
    xy = st_coordinates(polygon)[,1:2]

    ## compute the distance matrix and find largest element
    df_dist = as.matrix(dist(xy))
    maxij = findmax(df_dist)

    ## those elements define the largest chord
    chord = rbind(
        xy[maxij[1],],
        xy[maxij[2],]
    )
    chord
}


find_max_chord <- function(spolygon, chord=max_chord(spolygon)){

    ## Now compute the length and angle of the longest chord
    chord.length = sqrt(diff(chord[,1])^2 + diff(chord[,2])^2)
    chord.theta = atan2(diff(chord[,1]), diff(chord[,2]))

    ## The perpendicular is at this angle plus pi/2 radians
    perp = chord.theta + pi/2
    max_perp_chord(spolygon, perp, chord.length)
}
```

Here's how this goes together. The only dependency is `sf` - nothing else but base R is used:

```
library(sf)
```

Next massage your data into an `sf` polygon object:

```
## construct an sf polygon from points:
polygon = st_polygon(list(as.matrix(rbind(points_ex, points_ex[1,]))))
```

Get the max length chord between vertices:

```
chord = max_chord(polygon)
```

Plot the polygon and the chord and the chord points:

```
plot(polygon)
points(chord, col="red",cex=2)
lines(chord,col="green",lwd=2)
```

Now the meat. Get the chord perpendicular to the max chord through one of the polygon vertices:

```
## get the max perpendicular chord
pchord = find_max_chord(polygon, chord)
```

Plot it.

```
plot(pchord,add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I've tested this on another example, but not the second one you posted... Should work but...

It does...

[image]

Comment: Wow, yes, this is perfect! Thanks very much. I am also trying to get the chord that is perpendicular to the max chord, intersecting the max chord at its midpoint. Let's see how far I can get with that using your framework here. Thanks again!

Comment: Get the midpoint of `chord` easy enough (mean of X, mean of Y of the two chord points) then use `pline` to get a long perpendicular through that point. One thing not explained in the code is that the perpendicular is initially twice as long as `length` and its fed with the length of the longest chord. Since the perpendicular chord is shorter than the longest chord this guarantees the initial perpendicular won't fall short of the polygon when its clipped with st_intersect

Answer (score 1):

If your polygon is monotone, you can apply the next approach:

I assume that polygon is rotated to make the maximum length chord vertical (as your two images show).

Start from the top point. Traverse left part in CCW direction, right part in clockwise direction.

Key moment: the longest chord must touch some polygon vertex (because max cannot be reached on the line segment between two inner points at edges).

So get vertex with the highest Y-coordinate (either at the left part or at the right part). Calculate point at the edge on opposite side. Get length.

Get vertex with the next Y-coordinate. Calculate point at the edge on opposite side. Get length. Continue.